Do I need a transit visa for 16 hour lay over at Kuala Lumpur airport
I live in Australia but travel on my UK passport. Flying with air Asia and have 16 hour lay over at Kuala Lumpur Airport. Access to the air Asia lounge is outside the airport. Do I need a transit visa to leave the airport to get to the lounge and back into airport.
Thankyou in advance

No, you do not. British Citizens do not need visas to enter Malaysia for a visit. They do need to fill out a Malaysia Digital Arrival Card (MDAC) in advance.
The UK government maintains a very handy tool for checking this sort of information.
https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/malaysia/entry-requirements#:~:text=British%20nationals%20do%20not%20need,do%20not%20tolerate%20illegal%20immigration.
